# How to import GUI object that i wrote ( extends TextView ) in to the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wrote some class that extends `TextView` 
And now, I want to use this class in the layout.

So, I add some `TextView` object to the layout - and I change the name of the `TextView` to be `TextViewEx` - but its not working and  I don't know why.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the full package to the view. 
Instead of

```
<TextViewEx ... />
```

use

```
<com.yourapp.package.TextViewEx .. />
```

Comment: @Yanshof: This is the correct answer, so your code has problems. For example, make sure the class is `public` and has a `public` version of the two-parameter constructor (takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`). Here is an open source project of mine demonstrating a custom `View`, with the `demo/` sub-project demonstrating its use in a layout: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer

Comment: error that i get -   Element <com.yourapp.package.TextViewEx > is unknown.

Comment: You have to replace `com.yourapp.package` with the package name of your app of course (which i don't know). You specified that when creating your project. You can see it at the top of the views source file too.

Comment: And the error persists? In this case try to clean your project after replacing the package name. Project->Clean inside eclipse.

Comment: ok , its work - dont know how and why ... but suddenly its start to work.